# Azure AppGateway redirection to another host?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I want to implement the below redirection in Azure AppGateway v1

https://first.demo.com/home/ => https://second.demo.com/home/

is this doable? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple redirection to an external site can be achieved on Application gateway v1 but not a URL rewrite.
Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview

Application Gateway v2 and WAF v2 SKU supports the capability to add, remove, or update HTTP request and response headers, while the request and response packets move between the client and back-end pools. You can also rewrite URLs, query string parameters and host name. You can use server variables to evaluate rewrite conditions and rewrite headers.

Reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-portal

HTTP header and URL rewrite features are only available for the Application Gateway v2 SKU. So you cannot achieve the above requirement using Application gateway v1.

**Important points to consider:**

- In the case of a URL rewrite, Application Gateway rewrites the URL before the request is sent to the backend. This will not change what users see in the browser because the changes are hidden from the user.
- In the case of a URL redirect, Application Gateway sends a redirect response to the client with the new URL. That, in turn, requires the client to resend its request to the new URL provided in the redirect. The URL that the user sees in the browser will update to the new URL.

If you wish to upgrade your Application gateway from v1 sku to v2 sku, an Azure PowerShell script is available in the PowerShell gallery to help you migrate from your v1 Application Gateway/WAF to the v2 Autoscaling SKU. This script helps you copy the configuration from your v1 gateway. Traffic migration is still your responsibility.
For more information, please refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/migrate-v1-v2

Comment: does Application Gateway v1 support redirection?

Comment: Application gateway V1 supports below redirection capabilities:

1. Global redirection : Redirects from one listener to another listener on the gateway. This enables HTTP to HTTPS redirection on a site.
2. Path-based redirection : This type of redirection enables HTTP to HTTPS redirection only on a specific site area, for example a shopping cart area denoted by /cart/*.
3. Redirect to external site

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-overview